# Is it that there are alternatives to the security scan salesforce?

Tags: security-scanner, salesforcesdk

I'm wondering if there is some third party alternative or any alternative to the 
[Force.com Security Source Code Scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner).

I have ask to scan my org 1 week ago and I haven't get an answer yet. I have send a email to salesforce security team but not answer yet.

The last time I have done the same thing and get result in 1 or 2 days maximum.

Salesforce ask me to do a new annual security re-review but I can't get the scan result to do it.

I have found that I could use a plugin in eclipse to do a scan but I'm not getting the similar reports result that salesforce usually send by mail.

Comment: Salesforce should look into this seriously. It would be useful if the app predicts some time to expect the results. Unfortunately there is no indication for that. Experts can you take this issue to Salesforce. This would affect the development time when someone works in time crunch...